# Calling another function after value is not working

Tags: javascript

I have a simple code to call a value from another function and its not working :

```
function ABC() {
  var ID = XYZ(id);
  Logger.log(ID); //throws error not defined.
}

function XYZ(id) {
  var id = "1234"
  return id;
}
```

What I wan to do is capture the value of id from function XYZ and Logger.log it into function ABC. But this reflects error.

Comment: what is not defined? What is the actual error message? `XYZ(id);` <-- what is id here

Comment: "id" is not defined. id is "1234".

Comment: well where is it defined? `var ID = XYZ(id);` <-- The id that appears to be not defined

Comment: in function XYZ

Comment: no, that has NOTHING to do with that id.... you are passing it in....

Comment: Ok got your point but how will i call it then?

Comment: delete the `id` `var ID = XYZ();` and `function XYZ(){`

Comment: `id` isn't defined when you call `XYZ` so it throws an error. It might be helpful to provide a bit of context around the question, because the snippet, as asked, makes zero sense.

Comment: In think the error is before, when you're trying to call the XYZ function with a "id" var who doesn't exist.

Comment: ok I understand. But it does not make sense to me when there are multiple variables from XYZ example function `XYZ(id,url,name)` how will we know what variable we have to call in `ABC'.

Comment: @Mask The names of the arguments only matter inside the function that uses them. When passing values in from somewhere else (when you *call* the function), arguments are passed based on the order they appear. So first argument passed binds to the first parameter name defined in XYZ, second one passed binds to the second name, etc. You can call the parameters "one, two, three" and pass in variables "a, b, c" as arguments and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not sure what you are trying to do with your code. This code is an "Impure Function" which is not recommended in JavaScript. How much I understood your code, below are my suggestions:

**First**

```js
function abc() {
  var id = xyz();
  Logger.log(id);
}

function xyz() {
  // Add whatever logic you want here to return ID value
  var id = "1234"
  return id;
}
```

**Second**

```js
function abc() {
  // Pass any value as an argument based on your requirement
  var results = xyz('', '', '');
  Logger.log(results.id);
  Logger.log(results.name);
  Logger.log(results.number);
}

function xyz(id, name, number) {
  // Add whatever logic you want here 
  var newId = id || "1234";
  var newName = name || "Mask";
  var newNumber = number || "1234567890";
  return { id: newId, name: newName, number: newNumber };
}
```

Based on what suits your requirement, you can take help of these codes.

Comment: ok But I still have confusion what if there are multiple variables. for example :- id, name, number?

Comment: Where exactly ?

Comment: what if want to get more variable like id from `xyz(id,name,number){ retun id; return name; ....}`

Comment: You can have multiple return in a function. If you want to return multiple values then return an object like `return { id, name };`

Comment: and then call it by same name in function `abc(){ var id = xyz()[0]; var name = xyz()[1]; var number = xyz()[2]}` am i correct here?

Comment: Np, glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go -

```
function ABC() {
  var ID = XYZ();
  Logger.log(ID); // No longer throws the error :)
}

function XYZ() {
  var id = "1234"
  return id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need two functions, here is a simple function that will return the ID passed in.

```
const  ABC = (id) => {
    return id;
} 

let a = ABC(122443);
console.log(a) // output 122443
```